# click handler on bottom vaadin

Tags: java, vaadin7

I need to add a click Handler for a column in a table, so if the table has 3 row I need to add a clickhandeler for every row;
But I need also to add a value (to allow me to distinguish between rows) to the click handeler;
In other words:

I have this clickHandler:

```
btnElimina.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                    System.out.println( "nell handler  " );
                }
            });
```

and I should want some thing, like this:

```
btnElimina.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener(String Val) {

                @Override
                public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
                    System.out.println( "nell handler con "+ val );
                }           });
```

Is that possible? I've googled on it but didn't find a solution;
Also If I try to use the ClickEvent there seems nothing that I can use to distinguish between rows;

thanks for help

Comment: You should add which Vaadin version you're using. It seems to be some version before 10?

Comment: Yes indeed It Is 7.7.30

Comment: note that if you're using 7.7.30, you should have at least a Prime subscription, which means you're also eligible for commercial Vaadin support through Expert Chat.

Answer (score 1):

For Vaadin 7, you can find an example in the official documentation in the ["Components Inside a Table" section](https://vaadin.com/docs/v7/framework/components/components-table/#components.table.features.components). TLDR: you can use `setData()` / `getData()` from the Component to pass identifying information.

The relevant pieces are here:

```
Table table = new Table();
table.addStyleName("components-inside");

table.addContainerProperty("Details",        Button.class,    null);

/* Add a few items in the table. */
for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
    // The Table item identifier for the row.
    Integer itemId = new Integer(i);

    // Create a button and handle its click. A Button does not
    // know the item it is contained in, so we have to store the
    // item ID as user-defined data.
    Button detailsField = new Button("show details");
    detailsField.setData(itemId);
    detailsField.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
        public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
            // Get the item identifier from the user-defined data.
            Integer iid = (Integer)event.getButton().getData();
            Notification.show("Link " +
                              iid.intValue() + " clicked.");
        }
    });
    // Create the table row.
    table.addItem(new Object[] {detailsField},
                  itemId);
}
```

Comment: thanks, my explanation wasn't very good; I need to add a Listener in more than one column;

Comment: The same pattern applies any number of columns

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue in this way:

```
public class TableListe extends CustomComponent implements Button.ClickListener{
    
    private String istituto;
    
    public TableListe(String ista) {
        //super();      
        this.istituto = ista;
    }

    @Override
    public void buttonClick(ClickEvent event) {
        System.out.println( "  nell handler con this.istituto " + this.istituto);   
    }
}
```

It seems to work for now;